Why is Pharaoh without definite article?
The word פרעה (paroh, pharaoh) is mentioned more than 200 times in the Bible and it is always used without the definite article ה (ha), although titles usually have it like the word המלך (ha-melech, the king), which mentioned more than 800 times in the hebrew Bible and proper names like משה (Mosheh) and אברהם (Abraham) don't have it. But at the same time, it is unlikely that the authors of the Bible thought that "pharaoh" a proper name because there are multiple pharaohs in the Bible living in different periods. All of them having the same name wouldn't make sense. And one of them is mentioned by proper name (Hophra Jeremiah 44:30) after referring to him as "pharaoh".

It is a generic and descriptive concept since there were many of the title and since all of that many had the same characteristics (and character), therefore they can be considered as a concept rather than as individuals with personal attributes. A concept does not need an article if it is not being located to a specific example of that concept, just needs a label : a noun. Up-voted +1, good question. Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and functioning of the site,  also see the archive of questions and answers as to how this plays out in practice. Welcome to SE-BH.

Is Elohim the same kind of title?

200 times isn't that many for linguistic analysis. Pharaoh might have been an exceptional case. In Greece βασιλεύς without the article became specific to "the king of Persia" and that might be something that happens if speakers are constantly making a role synonymous with an individual. Or they might have somehow picked it up from the (much-earlier-to-contemporary) Hebrew usage. Or it might be coincidence. The Greek case is evidence the idiom can persist in natural language, even though English finds it peculiar.

We do something similar when we drop the definite article and refer to "the adversary" (ha-satan) by the proper name Satan. So it's possible that what was originally the name of an office of a wicked ruler (the pharaoh) became a proper name (Pharaoh) in a similar manner. However, I think there are other possible causes that are more likely.
One thing to consider in dealing with this question is the issue of when the definite article came into use. Experts in Egyptian language indicate this happened about 1400 bce. If one holds to an early date for the writing of the Torah (i.e. that it was written by Moses) this could mean that written references to the pharaohs did not yet contain the definite article. This would then form the tradition adopted throughout the Torah and some other parts of the OT to call this leader "pharaoh" rather than "the pharaoh."  There is also some question as to when the definite article came into use in the Hebrew language. 1
On the other hand, assuming a later date for writing of the Torah, it could be that its authors - in this case, not Moses - did not know the names of the older pharaohs and so simply called them "pharaoh." This hypothesis is supported by the fact that the Bible refers to later pharaohs by name such as "Shishak king of Egypt" (2 Samuel 8:7 etc.), "pharaoh Neco" (2 Kings 23:29 etc.) and "pharaoh Hophra king of Egypt" (Jeremiah 44:30).

The Hebrew text of Genesis 2:20 breaks the rule that “ha” is not used with a proper name. https://biblehub.com/text/genesis/2-20.htm

Adam can mean just a human being

haadam can mean man and man is an ambiguous word for a male or female, or mankind such as males and females, or any number of man. Adam is a name, and Genesis 2:20 in the first half uses the Hebrew word haadam which is not the name Adam.  haadam gave names to all the animals.   Adam is mentioned in the second half of the verse and is placed inside the Garden. haadam is a group of man, mankind, and  Adam is an individual person who could not find a partner and was placed in the Garden. https://biblehub.com/text/genesis/2-20.htm

My statement is that in Genesis 1&2 the English translation is breaking grammar rules by how “ha” is used with and without Adam.
